# Function to turn a string/regexp into a save filename

Tags: regex, r

I have a list of regexps which are used to produce some graphs. I'd like to save the graphs with it's corresponding regexp in the filename. Example:

```
re <- 'foo\\w{3}bar'
# ... produce a graph here and now need a filename
not_save <- paste0("pefix ", re, ".suffix")
```

But `re` needs to be cleaned from everyting not allowed in filenames. I know, it's OS and filesystem related, but I think if it's a valid filename on Windows it's valid everywhere.

I can substitute *bad* characters with `gsub()`:

```
not_save_enough <- gsub('[$^*|{}()/:]', '_', re, perl=TRUE)
```

But I don't know all *bad* chars and don't know how to replace `\` and/or `[` and `]`. Substitute all *bad* chars by `_` would be sufficient. Unfortunally things like

```
 gsub('\Q\\E', '_', "Numbers are \d", perl=TRUE)
```

arn't working even with `perl = TRUE` and produce

> Error: '\Q' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'/\Q"

Is there a function like `make_string_save_to_use_it_as_filename()`?

How to substitude `\`, `[` and `]` and other regexp-meta-chars in strings?

Comment: you need to double escape the `\Q`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks! That helps! But do you know if there is a function like I mentioned in the question? Seems strange to prepare strings for usage as filenames by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to substitude `\ [ ]` and other metacharacters in strings?

If the idea here is to replace bad characters, you may consider the POSIX class `[[:punct:]]`. This POSIX named class in the ASCII range matches all non-controls, non-alphanumeric, non-space characters.

```
!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~
```

So if you're wanting to replace each instance with an underscore you could do ...

```
fn <- gsub('[[:punct:]]', '_', 'foo\\w{3}bar')
# [1] "foo_w_3_bar"
```

The use of `\Q` and `\E` ensures that any character between will be matched literally and not interpreted as a metacharacter by the regular expression engine. Also in **R** the delimiter `/.../` and `g` (*global*) mode modifier syntax is invalid. Below is an example demonstrating the correct use:

```
x <- '[[[(((123]'
gsub('\\Q[[[(((\\E', '[', x, perl=T)
# [1] "[123]"
```

If you need to use modifiers, ensure `perl=TRUE` is turned on and use inline modifiers i.e. `(?ismx)`

Comment: I like the idea of using `[[:punct:]]` and will go with that. Thanks! Ok, `/.../g` is invalid syntax, I'll correct my question to not confuse someone. As Avinash mentioned, double escaping `\Q` works (`\\Q...\\E`). @hwnd

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this,

```
> re <- 'foo\\w{3}bar'
> not_save_enough <- gsub('[$^*|{}\\[\\]()/:\\\\]', '_', re, perl=TRUE)
> not_save_enough
[1] "foo_w_3_bar"
> re <- 'foo\\w{3}bar[foo]foo(buz)kj^jkj$jhh*foo|bar/hjh'
> not_save_enough <- gsub('[$^*|{}\\[\\]()/:\\\\]', '_', re, perl=TRUE)
> not_save_enough
[1] "foo_w_3_bar_foo_foo_buz_kj_jkj_jhh_foo_bar_hjh"
```

In R regex, you need to escape backslash three more times to match a literal backslash.